# Volley parrams, how to send the value 95 so the server won't receive "95" but it will receive 95

Tags: android, api, parameters, android-volley, endpoint

Ok so the problem is that I tested in Postman

```
{
    "country": "Australia",
    "windProbability": "90"
}
```

wont give me results
but

```
{
    "country": "Australia",
    "windProbability": 90
}
```

works fine

The problem is that when i send

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            String country = getIntent().getStringExtra("country");
            String windProbability = getIntent().getStringExtra("windProbability");
            if(country==null){
                country="";
                windProbability="";
            }
            params.put("country", country);
            params.put("windProbability", String.valueOf(windProbability));
            return params;
        }
```

the server receives

```
{
    "country": "Australia",
    "windProbability": "90"
}
```

Comment: I don't think its necessary .. Body will go as String you should modify your server logic for parsing the request .

Comment: @ADM the problem is that I created this app for an internship so I can't modify the servers logic as it is not on my side :|
The worst part is that I'm almost done..and I can't figure out how to get past this issue..

Comment: You can try using `Json` request https://stackoverflow.com/a/26347450/7995966 . I haven't used Volley since ages ..

Comment: @user3377063, You are sending `String` as  `windProbability String.valueOf(windProbability));` and on server response will response as `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove get params method and send like this. You cant send int value using getparams function.

```
        String url = "your url";
        JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
        try {
            postparams.put("country", "Australia");
            postparams.put("windProbability", 90); 
        // make it dynamic by declaring windProbalility as int
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG,postparams.toString());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, postparams,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {    

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                Log.e(TAG+"Error: ",error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, solved the problem. I'm so happy ATM :)

Comment: ATM ??. I am Jarin.   Any how am happy that your problem got  solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSONObject object to add up your request parameters instead of Map.

```
void sendTestRequest() throws JSONException {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
    jsonRequest.put("country", "Australia");
    jsonRequest.put("windProbability", 90);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonRequest,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: `Map<String, String>` will not accept an `Integer`.

Comment: Can you send me the snippet where you specify the volley request?

Comment: how can i send you? @noahutz

Comment: can you try the new solution?

Comment: I'm trying to see how to change my code with your solution to test it.

Comment: it would be best if you can provide the current codes. you can create a gist. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: ty, I was able to solve it, your answer was close but the guy above also had the Request.Method.POST and I tried his solution.
I up voted your answer but i have under 15 reputation so it won't appear :)